# Reorder dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm

I have the a dataframe, and want to reorder the rows such that the 2nd of the previous row is the same as the 1st of the next row, an example dataframe:

```
col1   col2
A      B
B      C
A      C
D      A
```

I'd want the output to look like this

```
col1   col2
D      A
A      B
B      C
```

such that the requirement above is filled and the output dataframe is as big as possible.
What would be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: whats in your actual df? alphabet like in the example?

Comment: can also be other strings

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention in the question, each original row can only appear once, and the output dataframe should be as big as possible

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's the higher-level goal here.

Comment: Please add the additional information into the question itself for future readers

Comment: In general, the problem seems to subsume the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understood the question fully, but if I did, here is an algorithmic approach which is pretty easy to handle:

**Intro:**

What you are essentially looking to do it to build a list of items according to some logic (`cur_item.first == prev_item.second`) and then show this list in descending/ascending order.

**Pseudocode:**

```
data = {}
for item in items:
    data[item.first] = item

list = []
// add the initial item to the list.
cur_item = list[0]

while condition:
    next_item = data[cur_item.second]
    list.append(next_item)
    cur_item = next_item
```

Hope this helps